# Can't render property in TempData, Object ref. not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a button for dequeuing my data from static variable, then I need to render a specific property on my view but for some reason I can't render it, the error message says
`Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
 maybe because it is null cuz I'm not yet enqueuing?, I guess? can someone provide an if statement? if thats the problem.

Here is my Controller :

```
public ActionResult BtnNext()
{
    var first = MyQueue.todayQueue.Dequeue();

    MyQueue.todayQueue.Count();

    TempData["QueueItem"] = first;

    return View("Index");
}
```

Here is my view:

```
    @{
        var item = (Rosh.QueueMe.Web.Models.MyQueue)TempData["QueueItem"];
    }
    <p>@item.QueueNumber</p>
```

Comment: How about `if (TempData["QueueItem"] != null)`?

Comment: You should not be using `TempData` to pass data to the view. Instead use `ViewBag`.

Comment: As mentioned above please try to use ViewBag or ViewData and have a check if it is null or not.